# Pandas column dict split to new column and rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dict in pandas dataframe column, the input is,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'A': {'k1': 10}}, {'A': {'k2': 20, 'k3': 30}}, {'A': {'k4': 15}}])

df
                        A
0             {u'k1': 10}
1  {u'k3': 30, u'k2': 20}
2             {u'k4': 15}
```

I would like to split the keys and values of `dict` in column 'A' to new columns and split to rows(depends on number of keys in the dict), basically output should look like,

```
  keys  values
0   k1      10
1   k3      30
2   k2      20
3   k4      15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension with flatenning for tuples and then `DataFrame` contructor:

```
L = [(k1, v1) for k, v in df['A'].to_dict().items() for k1, v1 in v.items()]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns = ['keys','values'])
print (df)
  keys  values
0   k1      10
1   k2      20
2   k3      30
3   k4      15
```

Or create `DataFrame` and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(df['A'].values.tolist())
       .stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
       .reset_index())
df.columns = ['keys','values']
print (df)
  keys  values
0   k1    10.0
1   k2    20.0
2   k3    30.0
3   k4    15.0
```

Answer (score 1):

***Option 1*** (If you have all unique keys in sub-dictionaries)
**`dict`** with **`collections.ChainMap`**

```
from collections import ChainMap   
dct = dict(ChainMap(*[i['A'] for i in d]))
pd.DataFrame(list(dct.items()), columns=['key', 'value'])

  key  value
0  k1     10
1  k4     15
2  k2     20
3  k3     30
```

***Option 2*** (If you might have duplicate keys)
**`itertools.chain.from_iterable`**

```
dct = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([i['A'].items() for i in d]))
df = pd.DataFrame(dct, columns=['key', 'value'])

  key  value
0  k1     10
1  k2     20
2  k3     30
3  k4     15
```