# Melt pandas dataframe containing column of dictionaries such that the dictionary values are also melted

Tags: python, pandas, merge, data-manipulation, json-normalize

## This is not a duplicate

This question: [Pandas column dict split to new column and rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50522146/pandas-column-dict-split-to-new-column-and-rows) does not answer the question within this post. I have included an approach to converting a column of dictionaries to a dataframe at the end of this post, that is not what I'm finding difficult here.

---

## Setup

Given the following data:

```py
d1 = {'a' : 12, 'b' : 44}
d2 = {'this' : 9, 'that' : 33, 'there' : 82}
d3 = {'x' : 19, 'y' : 38, 'z' : 12, 't' : 90}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    var_1 = [1,2,3],
    var_2 = ['one', 'two', 'four'],
    var_3 = [d1, d2, d3]
))
```

Which looks as:

```py
   var_1 var_2                                 var_3
0      1   one                    {'a': 12, 'b': 44}
1      2   two  {'this': 9, 'that': 33, 'there': 82}
2      3  four  {'x': 19, 'y': 38, 'z': 12, 't': 90}
```

I would like to be able to `.melt`, with particular `id_vars`, in a way which
also extracted the dictionaries from the `var_3` column.

Using *just* the first row:

```
   var_1 var_2                                 var_3
0      1   one                    {'a': 12, 'b': 44}
```

The expected interim result would be:

```
   var_1 var_2   key   value    
0      1   one    a     12
1      1   one    b     44
```

After melting this would be :

```
# using df.melt(id_vars = ['var_1', 'var_2'])

   var_1 var_2 variable value
0      1   one      key     a
1      1   one      key     b
2      1   one    value    12
3      1   one    value    44
```

I would like to do this across all the data.

## Attempt

To be honest I'm quite unsure how to go about this.

```py
# make key : value dataframe
row_i = 0
col_i = 2
key_value_df = (pd.DataFrame( df.iloc[ row_i, col_i], index= [0 ]  )
                    .T.reset_index()
                    .rename(columns = {'index' : 'key', 0 : 'value'})
            )

data_thing = (pd.concat( [pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[ 0 , [0,1]]
                    .to_dict(), index=[0])] * len(key_value_df) ))
```

Then

```py
data_thing.join(key_value_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

will give

```py
   var_1 var_2 key  value
0      1   one   a     12
1      1   one   a     12
```

But this feels like it could be dramatically improved, and i'm unsure about generalising it to other rows.

## Edit

I can get a column of dictionaries as a dataframe using something such as

```py
all_keys = functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y , [list(x.keys()) for x in var3])
all_values = functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [list(x.values()) for x in var3])
pd.DataFrame(dict( keys = all_keys, values = all_values ))
```

giving

```
    keys  values
0      a      12
1      b      44
2   this       9
3   that      33
4  there      82
5      x      19
6      y      38
7      z      12
8      t      90
```

**But this doesn't answer the question that I've asked**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using your `df`

```py
import pandas as pd

var3 = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(df['var_3'].values.tolist()).stack().reset_index(level=1))
var3.columns = ['keys','values']

print(var3)

    keys    values
0   a       12.0
0   b       44.0
1   this    9.0
1   that    33.0
1   there   82.0
2   x       19.0
2   y       38.0
2   z       12.0
2   t       90.0

df = df.join(var3)

print(df)
```

[image]

### `pd.json_normalize`

- This might be better

```py
var3 = pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(df.var_3).stack()).reset_index(level=1)
var3.columns = ['keys','values']
```

Comment: thank you Trenton, i just realised that this works because the index value is retained, enabling the join to use that later. I almost never do that, so this was quite informative for me. Cheers :)  (initially I was surprised that join knew how many of each to retain ha...)

Comment: Yes, that's a gotcha.  Everyone wants a nice `0...n` index, but then you can't `join`.

Answer (score -1):

```
def custom_melt(df):
    vals = []
    for row in df.itertuples():
        for k, v in row.var_3.items():
            vals.append({'var_1': row.var_1,
                         'var_2': row.var_2,
                         'variable': 'key',
                         'value': k})
            vals.append({'var_1': row.var_1,
                         'var_2': row.var_2,
                         'variable': 'value',
                         'value': v})
    return pd.DataFrame(vals).sort_values(['var_1', 'var_2', 'variable'])
```

Output

```
>>>custom_melt(df)
    var_1 var_2 variable  value
0       1   one      key      a
2       1   one      key      b
1       1   one    value     12
3       1   one    value     44
```

Comment: using nested for loops, and hard coding the column names, makes me a little uneasy here